# How can an enum be re-exported?

Tags: module, rust

This gives me an error:

```
mod foo {
  pub enum T {
    Foo,
  }
}

mod bar {
  pub type T = ::foo::T;
}

fn main() {
  let _ = bar::T::Foo; // error: no associated item named `Foo` found for type `foo::T` in the current scope
}
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26264

Comment: Please note that the Rust style is 4-space indents.

Comment: @Shepmaster The Rust style is silly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue, [#26264](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26264).

You should `pub use foo::T;` instead. `type` is purely an alias, with its intention being the combination of types and filling in of generics (e.g. `type Foo = Bar<Baz>;`), so for public reexporting it won’t do what you want anyway.

Comment: This is actually for the sake of filling in generics; the actual use case is http://pastebin.com/DYDJjFLs. Good to know it's an open issue though, thanks!

In the meantime, I've just added a `use foo::T::*;`